# java get difference between two images in percent

Tags: java, image

I have the following code:

```
private static int pixelDiff(int rgb1, int rgb2) {
    int r1 = (rgb1 >> 16) & 0xff;
    int g1 = (rgb1 >>  8) & 0xff;
    int b1 =  rgb1        & 0xff;
    int r2 = (rgb2 >> 16) & 0xff;
    int g2 = (rgb2 >>  8) & 0xff;
    int b2 =  rgb2        & 0xff;
    return Math.abs(r1 - r2) + Math.abs(g1 - g2) + Math.abs(b1 - b2);
}
```

and it works without a problem, but it takes to long and i don't know how it optimize it.

So the basic is, that i want to compare two images and get the percentage of difference.

Therefor I load the RGB of both images and compare them with this code.

My question: Is it possible to optimize this code, or do you have any idea to compare two images(not only that they are equal)

**UPDATE:**

here is the full code:

```
private double getDifferencePercent(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {

    int width = img1.getWidth();
    int height = img1.getHeight();
    int width2 = img2.getWidth();
    int height2 = img2.getHeight();
    if (width != width2 || height != height2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Images must have the same dimensions: (%d,%d) vs. (%d,%d)", width, height, width2, height2));
    }

    long diff = 0;
    for (int y = height - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
        for (int x = width - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            diff += pixelDiff(img1.getRGB(x, y), img2.getRGB(x, y));
        }
    }
    long maxDiff = 765L * width * height;

    return 100.0 * diff / maxDiff;
}

private static int pixelDiff(int rgb1, int rgb2) {
int r1 = (rgb1 >> 16) & 0xff;
int g1 = (rgb1 >>  8) & 0xff;
int b1 =  rgb1        & 0xff;
int r2 = (rgb2 >> 16) & 0xff;
int g2 = (rgb2 >>  8) & 0xff;
int b2 =  rgb2        & 0xff;
return Math.abs(r1 - r2) + Math.abs(g1 - g2) + Math.abs(b1 - b2);
}
```

I checked this with a profiler and it shows that pixelDiff() is very slow.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] (including input/output). What you're showing is just comparing a single pixel, and is pretty much instantaneous to run. / Benchmark your code and show which part is running slow

Comment: width up to 400; height up to 700